# Web2py. json field returned a str where previously returned a dict

Tags: web2py

I updated from web2py v2.14.6 to v2.18.2

In db.py

`Field('address', 'json', custom_qualifier={'indexed':False})`

From a modules .py:

`geo_address_row = db(db.geo_address.latlonkey == latlonkey).select(db.geo_address.latlonkey).first()`

Where `geo_address_row.address` was a dict I now have a `str` and have to wrap it, thus: `json.loads(geo_address_row.address)`

The data was written before the Web2py update.

Is there enough details here for anyone to identify why my code worked before but not now?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug and is being fixed a new release of Web2py.
[Issue Closed](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/issues/2121)